# No Dev hub available in Enterprise Edition too

Tags: salesforcedx, setup, sfdx-falcon

Dev hub missing in set up:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am system admin in my enterprise org, but still I am unable to view dev hub in this org? Is there any other way I can enable dev hub?

Because as per doc :

Available in: Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience
Dev Hub available in: Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions
Scratch orgs available in: Developer, Enterprise, Group, and Professional Editions

Comment: Are you in a trial? Is it a Dev Org trial?

Comment: Its our production org. Enterprise Edition, I have pasted image for reference.

Comment: You can have an Enterprise Org but it be a Trial, like if you've created it in the past 30 days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Edition orgs are supposed to have this feature. If you do not have this feature, and you are not in a Trial Period, contact Technical Support to have this feature enabled. If you are in a Trial, this feature (as well as all other limited features) will be unlocked when your subscription becomes active.

Comment: I just quried and found this : `Select ID, TrialExpirationDate from Organization WHERE Id = '00D1I000002MUCz'`  


2018-11-07T04:50:23.000+0000

Comment: As the trial expiration date is till Nov, shouldn't dev hub be enabled.

Comment: @RahulJain Active orgs have a *null* TrialExpirationDate. You're on a Trial (just a really *long* one, apparently). You might be able to get this enabled through Technical Support, but I don't know what the rules for that are. Try opening a case with Support.